# Iterating over two zipped files (python's mapping)

Tags: zip, python-3.3

The following is advised by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2323422/1575066) (as big files do not allow `zip(file1, file2)`):

```
from itertools import izip
for i, j in izip(file1, file2):
```

However, this is not available in python 3.3 for some reason.

What is the alternative in Python 3.3 when one needs to iterate over 2 files simultaneously?

Comment: I suspect that they improved on `zip()`, making `izip()` obsolete, but I can't find proof.

Answer (score 0):

in python 3, `izip` does no longer exists and `zip` returns an iterator, like `izip` used to do. Same thing apply to `range`/`xrange`.

as a reference:

- https://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists
- https://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#overview-of-syntax-changes