# Python - read file, find hidden message in a passage

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to open a file with an encrypted message in it, e.g. a passage from a book.

1. Load the passage as a single string.
2. Remove any characters that are not letters.
3. Break the string into a table, with at least 5 characters in each row.
4. Use a sequence of numbers `4,5,4,3,1,1,2,3,4,5` to index each row.

The result should be something like:

```
  was h er
thise e
 fret l
   rj l
    d o
```

This is what I have so far:

```
def cipher():
   f = open("cipher.txt", "r")
   fileString = f.readline()
   for line in fileString:
       lineSplit = line.split()
```

Comment: Post your code or prepare for a flood of downvotes.

Comment: your code shows oppening one file, but doesn't show how you know what the indexes are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of your indexes are off by one, so I've corrected them to: `3,5,4,2,1,1,2,3,4,5`.

Below is the code you need, the problem was that you were only iterating through the lines and not extracting anything from them. Mostly because your function took no input.

This method takes a file-like object and an list of integers as a "key":

```
def cipher(encrypted,key):
    return "".join([line[offset] for offset,line in zip(key,encrypted.readlines())])
```

Expanded out this is:

```
def cipher(encrypted,key):
    message=[]
    for offset,line in zip(key,encrypted.readlines()):
        message.append(line[offset]
    return "".join(message)
```

or building the string as you go (which might take longer as arrays are mutable, whereas this would require building a new string every iteration):

```
def cipher(encrypted,key):
    message=""
    for offset,line in zip(key,encrypted.readlines()):
        message = message + line[offset]
    return message
```

This takes the key and encrypted files and [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip)s them together to make an accessible tuple, which we use to index into each line of the file. If the file could be quite long, you might want to use [`izip` from `itertools`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323394/zip-alternative-for-iterating-through-two-iterables) to zip using iterable instead of lists in memory.

And returns the text.

Here is an example program that calls it:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
f = StringIO("""washer
thisee
fretl
rjl
do""")
print cipher(f,[3,5,4,2,1,1,2,3,4,5])
```

And when run prints:

```
>>> hello
```

Comment: is it possible if you could convert the code to python 3 its throwing all kinds of errors all over the place

Comment: I don't use Python 3, and it wasn't mentioned in the question. I can expand the answer out so the algorithm is more visible.

Comment: @bisera I've expanded it out, so I hope that helps.

Comment: What about it I wanted to display like how the example above suggests to print the original word then space then space then the word