# Logging to two CSV files in parallel (python)

Tags: python, csv

I am reading a series of climate data text files, each file contains 9000 lines, the first line is the stations' information like name, longitude, ...etc.
The lines from 8 to the end contain the climate data.

I want to read all the files and output two files "MetLocations.csv" and "MetData.csv", where the first file consists of a collection of the first lines' of all files, while the second file consists of all the climate data.

I looped through all the files, read the information, and printed them with no problem except one strange problem. when I make a double 'with' loops, the file MetLocations.csv is left empty, while when I make them in loop by loop, it writes well! *Please see the code for clearer view.*

This is part of my code:

```
with open('MetLocations.csv','wb+') as locations:
    wr_loc = csv.writer(locations, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar='', delimiter=',', escapechar='\\')
    headers = ["St_Id","City","State","Country","Source","WO code","Lat","Long","TimeZone","Alt"]
    wr_loc.writerow(headers)
    with open('MetData.csv','a+')as met_data:
        wr_data = csv.writer(met_data, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar='', delimiter=',', escapechar='\\',lineterminator='\n')
        headers = ["St_ID", "Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour", "Minute", "Data Source and Uncertainty Flags", "Dry Bulb Temperature"]
        wr_data.writerow(headers)

            for n, f in enumerate(filenames):
                print n, f,time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                full_path = os.path.join(source, f)
                with open(full_path, 'r') as input_file:
                    content = input_file.readlines()
                    location = [n] + list_elements(content[0])[1:]
                    wr_loc.writerow(location)
                    meteo = []
                    for line in content[8:]:
                        meteo.append([n] + list_elements(line))
                    wr_data.writerows(meteo)
```

At the end of running the code above, I found the file MetData.csv full of data, while the file MetLocations.csv is empty!

The strange thing, that when I run the same code with the last 4 bottom lines commented, the MetLocations.csv is filled without problems!

Is it not allowable to open two sequential CSV files for appending?
or What is the wrong part in my code?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323394/zip-alternative-for-iterating-through-two-iterables

Comment: @ِAri Gold, Thanks, but the mentioned question is about reading files in parallel, not writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to open all the files in the same line, so that the are part of the same context:

```
with open('MetLocations.csv','wb+') as locations, open('MetData.csv','w')as met_data:

     wr_loc = csv.writer(locations,
                         quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,
                         quotechar='', delimiter=',', escapechar='\\')

     wr_data = csv.writer(met_data,
                          quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,
                          quotechar='', delimiter=',',
                          escapechar='\\',lineterminator='\n')

     headers = ["St_Id","City","State","Country","Source","WO code","Lat","Long","TimeZone","Alt"]
     wr_loc.writerow(headers)

     headers = ["St_ID", "Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour", "Minute", "Data Source and Uncertainty Flags", "Dry Bulb Temperature"]
     wr_data.writerow(headers)

     for n, f in enumerate(filenames):
         print n, f,time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
         full_path = os.path.join(source, f)
         with open(full_path, 'r') as input_file:
            # your code here
```

Comment: I will try it now, If succeeded, I will mark as Accepted., Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, It fails as well! The MetLocations.csv still blank

Comment: It cannot be blank, it should have the header row; unless you have some other code surrounding this code.

Comment: Even the header row is not written unless I commented the last four lines! I do not have hidden code, Very Strange!, isn't it?

Comment: What last four lines exactly are you talking about?

Comment: the lines started from `meteo = []` and ends in `wr_data.writerows(meteo)`

Comment: Make sure your for loop isn't indented any further along in your actual code; it should be at the same block as the `headers =  ` line.

Comment: No, the writing statement is indented two blocks more, because of the `filenames` for loop and the `with open` loop, as you see in the initial code.

Comment: Your answer finally works, but the run must complete to the end to see the `MetLocations.csv` file, while the other file  `MetData.csv` is filled gradually! 

I stop the run to see  what is going on, as they are more than 10000 files to process. Thanks